# Glueing image to top of UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone development question:

How can I put an image above a grouped UITableView that scrolls along with the table view? (The image should be attached to the top of the table view, so when scrolling the table view, the image should scroll out of the screen along with the table view. The image is NOT a fixed position subview as in similar postings)

I tried setting backgroundColor with colorWithPatternImage and adding EdgeInsets to push the table view down, but then the image displays non-scrolling behind the table view, AND the image displays also behind each and every section in the table view (scrolling).

The only solution I have come up with is to let cellForRowAtIndexPath return an image for the first section in the table view, though this feels like a hack.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: This one is solved. But can anyone explain why tableView.backgroundColor = ...colorWithPatternImage... renders the image in a fixed position behind the table view, and then repeats the image for every section in the table? (I even think the phone and the simulator gave very different visuals here)

Comment: I believe Apple's engineers designed it that way to reduce compositing operations -- transparency is expensive for scroll views, so they optimized for a vertical striped pattern, which allows the section background views to be opaque (since they look exactly like the background behind them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to put an image at the top of a table view would be to set the table view's `tableHeaderView` property with an instance of `UIImageView` containing the image.

Comment: One more thing: Now the table view starts directly below the header image. How can I make the table view start about halfway down the header image (so the gradient of the header image continues along the sides of the table view)?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`.
Identify section 0 and add Image in that customize view with your section header.

your implementation looks like:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
         // init your view
         // Add Image in view
         // Add Header for section manage frames
    }
    else {
         // Add Header for section manage frames
    }
}
```

Hope this helped